# stop subscription in iron router after rendering all the data

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using a package that makes a reactive version of DataTables called aldeed:tabular. When retrieving a large amount of documents, it tends to slow down the server considerably, to the point where any other queries take 30 seconds to load, when normally they would load up after a second or two. 
I figured that it might have to do with maintaining the subscription while the user is on the page, so I want to stop the subscription once all the data is loaded, effectively killing the reactivity.

I am using iron-router, and this is my current controller:

```
  waitOn: function () {
  this.subscribe("Suites",Session.get("query"));
  this.subscribe("JobsStatuses",Session.get("query"));

      },
 onRun: function () {
    Session.set("query",this.params.query);
    this.next();
  },
  onRerun: function () {
    this.next();
  },
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    this.next();
  },
```

I tried creating two functions that return the subscription handler and pass them into 'waitOn' and then refer to the same handlers in 'onBeforeAction' to stop them once it finished rendering, but I don't think I can define a function in here to do that.

Any advice on how to stop subscription in iron router after rendering?

EDIT:
There are 2 million documents within the collection and we do have indexes for name and changelist . 
this is the publish code that I am using:

```
Meteor.publish('Suites', function (query) {
  var self = this;
  if (query === null) {
      this.ready();
      return;
  }
  if (query.name !== undefined) {
      query.parent_name = {$regex:query.name};
      delete query.name;
  }
  if (query.changelist !== undefined) {
      query.changelist = parseInt(query.changelist);
  }
  if (query.suite !== undefined) {
      delete query.suite;
  }
  var suites = {};
  var handle = Jobs.find (
        {$and : [query ,{parent_name:{$exists:1}}]}
  ).forEach(function(cl) {
      var suite = cl.suite;
      var status = cl.status;
      if (suites[suite] === undefined) {
          suites[suite] = {};
      }
      if (suites[suite][status] === undefined) {
          suites[suite][status] = 0;
      }
      suites[suite][status]++;
    });
    self.added('Suites', new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(), suites);
    self.ready();
});

Meteor.publish('JobsStatuses', function (query) {
  if (query === null) {
      this.ready();
      return;
  }
  if (query.name !== undefined) {
      query.parent_name = {$regex:query.name};
      delete query.name;
  }
  if (query.changelist !== undefined) {
      query.changelist = parseInt(query.changelist);
  }

  var self = this;

  var num_passed = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var pipeline = [];
  var handle = Jobs.find (
        {$and : [query ,{parent_name:{$exists:1}}]},
        { status:1 }
  ).forEach(function(cl) {
        total++;
        if (cl.status === "passed") {
          num_passed++;
        }
      // Store the status as the _id
    });
    self.added('JobsStatuses', new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(), {
        "num_passed":num_passed,
        "total":total
    });
    self.ready();
});
```

the query that is passed to the publication can call for name only, which results in potentially 10000 documents or more. We are usually allowing the client to search by changelist and name, which results in up to about a few hundred documents.

The obvious solution is to not allow clients to search by name only, and always look for the latest changelist, but I still want to display the results non reactivity, whether it is by using subscription and then stopping it, or not using subscription at all and interacting with Mongo in a server request-response manner.

Comment: How many documents are you dealing with? It may be useful for you to post your actual publication code as well in case there is something you have done that is slowing it down. Also, it may help to add an index to the collection.

Please post your publication code so I can see what it is searching for

Comment: I have updated the OP.

Comment: The data transformation you're doing in your publish is not helping either. Slow.... Should you be using a `transform` on your collection instead? Stopping the subscription will cause minimongo to flush the data from the client. You can easily implement server-side search so that you don't have to copy all the data to the client and search it there (which is also very slow).